# Rounding numbers in Raster Legend in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, legend

Is it possible to have the numbers in the raster legend automatically rounded off?

In the example below I'd like the labels to be 8, 29, 51 and so on.

I know I can manually edit the labels, but is it really necessary to do that every time I make a map?

[image: example]

Comment: Can you select Pretty Breaks in the Mode?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the Mode". I haven't seen an option for pretty breaks anywhere in neither properties, style manager, settings, print composer or anywhere else I've tried to find a solution.

Comment: On your screenshot look under the values, its the next drop down box.

Comment: Ah, that Mode. Nope, there's only Continuous, Equal interval and Quantile, and neither are very "pretty".

Comment: "Pretty Breaks" mode is currently only available for vector layers. There's an open feature request to implement it for rasters: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of QGIS 3.16, you can do this directly via the Label precision option under Symbology.

Just set the precision to 0.

You can also use negative numbers to round to powers of 10.

[image]

Comment: Slightly late Tom :-), and not an option when I asked the question, but today it is the correct answer.

Answer (score -3):

If you have edited them manually, you can copy the style by right clicking on the layer name in your layers panel.

If you added another raster, you can paste the style by also right clicking on the layer name.

[image]

If it isn't necessary to have the same intervals in multiple layers, but just integer values in your layer, you can select "Discrete" as Interpolation and "Quantile" as Mode, and then click on the Classify button.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but that also copies the range of the colorscale, which may be different for the next map (and in my case almost always will be). So if I do that I'll have to change the min/max values, and then the decimals are back again.

Comment: Did you set the Interpolation to Discrete?

Comment: No, I'm using linear. I just tried changing to discrete, though; it doesn't change the legend.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the last two lines of your reply now. Using discrete as interpolation and then classifying still produces decimal numbers unless (max - min)/<number of intervals> is an integer.

Comment: I edited my answer. If I combine Discrete with Quantile I always get integers.

Comment: Quantile actually doesn't give a very good representation of my data, but I just tested it anyway, and I still get decimal numbers. Looks like the labels defaults to 3 significant digits unless there's trailing zeros after a decimal point, in which case they are truncated.

Comment: It seems to me that the question was trying to ask for an automated way of rounding the display for a legend. This answer instead addresses transferring styles between rasters. If the answer is that there is no automated way to do this, it would be useful to know that.